# How to memorize an action before the position was taken

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to set my stop loss at the last pivot point that happened before the position opened and save it. My issue is that I don't succeed in saving it so it will always move and follow the position everytime the market make a new pivot point.

Here is the code for the pivot point :

```
// PIVOTS
lengthGroupTitle = "LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
colorGroupTitle = "Text Color / Label Color"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High", group=lengthGroupTitle)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High", group=lengthGroupTitle)
textColorH = input(title="Pivot High", defval=color.black, inline="Pivot High", group=colorGroupTitle)
labelColorH = input(title="", defval=color.white, inline="Pivot High", group=colorGroupTitle)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=lengthGroupTitle)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=lengthGroupTitle)
textColorL = input(title="Pivot Low", defval=color.black, inline="Pivot Low", group=colorGroupTitle)
labelColorL = input(title="", defval=color.white, inline="Pivot Low", group=colorGroupTitle)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)
lastph = ph
lastpl = pl

drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _color, _textColor) =>
    if not na(_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, str.tostring(_pivot, format.mintick), style=_style, color=_color, textcolor=_textColor)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `var` variable

> var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.
>
> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t
> include the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being
> overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when
> assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state”
> despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within
> if-expressions are met.

Or use `ta.valuewhen()`

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.
>
> ta.valuewhen(condition, source, occurrence) → series float

```
//@version=5
indicator("ta.valuewhen")
slow = ta.sma(close, 7)
fast = ta.sma(close, 14)
// Get value of `close` on second most recent cross
plot(ta.valuewhen(ta.cross(slow, fast), close, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you.
I tried but I can't figured out how can I apply it to the last pivot high before my position was open and keep this value as my stop loss